What group is presented by $\{a,b\mid aaa,aba'bbbab'\}$ and what is its order?
So far I've been able to resolve all finite groups presented by relators with a total length of 11 except this one.  I've run Todd-Coxeter until I ran past 256GB of memory; I've run Knuth-Bendix for two solid weeks (even with equivalent presentations with different generator/relator orders).  Some things I do know:
The generator $b$ has order 9 (or 3 if the group collapses in a very strange way).
I've found quotient groups of index 1, 3, 9, 19, 27, 28, 36, 171, 1512, 4536, and 86,184 (so I know the group is either infinite or has order greater than or equal to 86,184).
The group is not Abelian.
There is no low-index subgroup that is an Abelianization group (with index less than 40).
I've been reading various texts on finitely-presented groups (including Johnson and Holt, Rees, and Rover) without yet being able to crack this one.  I've used ACE, MAF, and GAP (including making MAF compile properly with modern compilers; source on github.)
I've even found a bug in GAP in this effort (which has been fixed).  But after weeks of getting nowhere I thought I'd ask for help.

Presumably, $x'$ means $x^{-1}?$ The notation is unusual, though.

If $b$ has order three, then that second generator collapses to $a$, so $a$ is the identity, so you just have the cyclic group of order three. So (assuming the rest of your work is correct) it's safe to say $b$ has order nine.

What Gerry said. The second relation shows that $b^3$ is conjugate to $a^{-1}$. So if you have found a quotient group where $a$ is mapped to something non-trivial, it follows that $b$ has order nine.

Mind you, it would be nice if you shared a non-trivial quotient group (=a homomorphic image), where both $a$ and $b$ are non-trivial. May be also a quotient group that isn't a 3-group?

If you add the relation $(ab)^6$, you get a quotient group of index 1512.  If you add the (admittedly long) relation $a'b'a'b'b'abbabbba'b'a'b'abbab'b'$, you get a quotient group of index 86,184.  If you add the commutator $[a,b]$ (meaning $aba'b'$), you get a quotient group of index 9.
My best hope at the moment is that adding the relations $(ab)^{3n}$ leads to an infinite series of distinct quotient groups, but the code I have can't resolve $n>5$ yet.

Ok, so you don't have some "known" groups as homomorphic images? Like permutations (or matrices) satisfying both relations?

Here's one, with order 86,184:  $(1,7,2)(3,6,8)(4,5,9)(10,28,21)(11,25,13)(12,20,26)(14,18,22)(15,27,24)(16,
17,23), (1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2)(10,21,11,27,19,23,12,20,24)(13,22,25,14,15,26,
28,18,16)$.

Grand! Thanks!!

I think this class of problems is undecidable.

It is indeed undecidable in general, but any particular instance may well be within the abilities of our current mathematics, just like the Busy Beaver problem.  I would be shocked if the answer to this case required anything non-elementary; I just haven't been able to resolve it yet.
